Salesforce Marketing Cloud: Private Domain vs. Verified Domain
I'm trying to understand the difference between Private Domain and Verified Domain in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.
I get that a Private Domain offers full DKIM, SPF, and DMARC authentication for your custom domain, which can significantly improve email deliverability.
However, I've noticed that Constant Contact allows you to add these authentication records yourself. So, is a Private Domain strictly necessary in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, or can I achieve similar results by manually adding the authentication records?
I'd appreciate any insights or experiences you might have on this topic. Thanks in advance!

Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Even though it is tempting, I will not recommend to use Verified Domain for sending your emails. There are no shortcuts to authentication here, so you will need to ask Salesforce for a a Private Domain. You are theoretically correct, that you could add the authentication records yourself, this is common if you chose to self-host DNS for a Private Domain. But how would you know which values to add in your e.g. DKIM?
Emails sent from SFMC are signed with a DKIM key, which the recipient can verify against the DKIM record in the DNS. In case these don't match, the email will not be delivered. As SFMC does not sign emails with the DKIM for the verified domains, you will not have any luck going in this direction.
Here is an extensive guide on Private Domains, Email Authentication etc. It also touches upon Private Domain vs Verified Domain question.
